# Returning the search query of the entire table

Tags: php, mysql

I have set the task before me to use PHP in doing the following work on MySQL table:

1. Take the search input from HTML form and put it in the `$POST['search']`
2. Select table data
3. Number the table rows and put the number of rows into  variable
4. Take the first value from the first row and check if it is equal to `$POST['search']`. If it is, print it together with the column name.
5. Take the n-th value from the first row and check if it is equal to `$POST['search']`. If it is, print it together with the column name.

Repeat that for each row of the table

I solved the HTML form, database connection, select table data and numbering the table rows (1,2 and 3)

I need help with 4 and 5.

Here is the code so far:

```
    // 1 Izvuci podatke iz tabele
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = '';
$table = '';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");


// sending query 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");

}

// count the rows 

$row_num= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table}");
```

Can someone help me continue ?

Thank you.

Comment: if you're really using `$POST['search']` it's the wrong syntax for that superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php so be precise as to the exact syntax you're really using or wanting to use.